# How to use migrate Vue 2 $on, $emit event bus to Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I transform this VueJS v2 code to v3?

```js
window.Eventing = new (class {
    constructor() {
        this.vue = new Vue();
    }
    fire(event, data = null, subdata = null) {
        this.vue.$emit(event, data, subdata);
    }
    listen(event, callback) {
        this.vue.$on(event, callback);
    }
})();
```

Comment: There is a migration guide for Vue 2 to Vue 3, which specifically states that Vue3 no longer supports this use case of Vue as an event bus. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html#migration-strategy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue 3 no longer supports the event emitting API from its prototype (including `$emit` and `$on`), but you could switch to a different event emitter library, such as [`tinyemitter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinyemitter) (good for CDN usage) or [`tiny-emitter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-emitter), which has a close API to the original in Vue 2:

```js
import TinyEmitter from 'tinyemitter'

window.Eventing = new (class {
    constructor() {
        this.emitter = new TinyEmitter();
    }
    fire(event, data = null, subdata = null) {
        this.emitter.emit(event, data, subdata);
    }
    listen(event, callback) {
        this.emitter.on(event, callback);
    }
})();
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/OJWYyOa?editors=1010)

Comment: better use a tiny-emitter package.
///////////
tiny-emitter - 1,398,006 downloads per month and published 5 years ago.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-emitter
///////////
tinyemitter - 34 downloads per month and published 6 years ago.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tinyemitter

Comment: and better solution - mitt 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt